# how can i export a module from one angular2-cli project to another?

Tags: angular

I want to copy a singular madule from on project to another without hard copy.
and need a dependency manager like npm to handle this problem. my two project develop in one company & i can clone two project in on pc.

i want to export a module from one project and import this module to another project with typescript export&import.

please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in order to publish an angular library first of all you should create your own public API module (**project 1**), and with a packager (like ng-Packagr) pack the library. and finally use your library in other projects **(project 2**)

***project 1:***

1. in the @NgModule decorator, identify the export components, in export array section, like below example:

`exports: [ReviewComponent, ]`

2. and modify package.json file. identity packager in script section:

   `"scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e",
   **"packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"**
   }`
3. create ng-package.json config:

   // here is an example
   `{
     "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
     "lib": {
       "entryFile": "public_api.ts",}
   }`
4. create public_api.ts config. that say's which module should be packed for export purpose:

`export * from './src/app/reg-review/reg-review.module'`

5. run the following command:

`npm run packagr`

- after your package is created go to the dist subfolder and run this command:
  `npm pack`

***project 2:***

- refrence to the library( which were build in dist subfolder of project 1)`npm install ../ngLibs/reg/registeration-0.0.0.tgz --save`

  - import your desigerd module and use it
    import { RegisterReviewModule } from 'registeration'

you can take advantage of these addresses:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr

https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple options here, depending on what you want to achieve you might pick one over another:

- there can be multiple apps within the same CLI project, the apps property in the config file is an array
- one can use tools like [ng-packagr](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr) to extract and publish external modules
- one can use [Nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx) to manage all apps and libraries in a monorepo like approach
- could use [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/) to achieve a similar monorepo approach
- if you want to share components look at tools like [Bitsrc](https://bitsrc.io)
- etc.

In the end it's about what requirements you have and how you want to work within your company.